# avoid sorting in X axis in matplotlib and plot common X axis with multiple y axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I wish to clarify two queries in this post.

I have a pandas df like below picture.
[image]

**1. Plotting problem :** .
When i try to plot `column 0 with column 1`, the values gets sorted.

example : in `col_0` I have values starting from `112 till 0`.
the values gets sorted in ascending order and the graph shows reversed X axis plot when i use the below code.

```
plt.plot(df.col_0, df.col_1)
```

[image]

What will be best way to avoid sorting X axis values. ?

**2. All paramaters in single graph**
I would like to plot all the params in a single plot. Except X axis all other params values are between `0 to 1` (same scale)
What will be best pythonic way of doing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to draw everything against (the reverse order of) `col0`?

Comment: Try inverting the x-axis using `plt.gca().invert_xaxis()` and see if this is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to draw the series/dataframe against the index:

```
col_to_draw = [col for col in df.columns if col!='col0']

# if your data frame is indexed as 0,1,2,... ignore this step
tmp_df = df.reset_index()

ax = tmp_df[col_to_draw].plot(figsize=(10,6))
xtick_vals = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticklabels(tmp_df.col0[xtick_vals].tolist())
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by they get sorted - does it not plot 112, 0.90178 and connect it to 110.89899, 0.90779, etc?

To share the X axis but have 2 Y axes that certain sets are plotted on, [use twinx](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/two_scales.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-two-scales-py)

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(df.col_0, df.col_1)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(df.col_0, df.col_2)
```

re: how to plot in the order you want

I believe your intention is to actually plot these values vs. time or index. To that end, I suggest:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(df['Time'], df.col_0) # or df.index, df.col_0
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(df['Time'], df.col_1)
```

Comment: sorted : it plotted in ascending order. Like My data starts from 112 till 0 but it gets plotted from 0 to 112 in x axis. (Refer picture in my question)

Comment: Are you saying you want the axis to be reversed? Or that you actually want to plot time vs. speed?